# Redux Saga: difference between yield array to fork in the root saga

Tags: redux, redux-saga

New to saga, I'm using this in my root saga:

```
function* rootSaga() {
    yield [
        cycleRoot(), // fetches root
        cycleChain(), // fetch chain
        cycleChatBadge(), // fetches badge
        watchNotifications(), // navigate on ROOT_DONE
        watchNavigation(), // listen to navigation changes
        watchAppState(), // background/foreground
        watchConnection(), // connection chages
    ];
}
```

It works. However I've seen examples which use:

```
function* rootSaga() {
    yield fork (cycleRoot);
    yield fork (cycleChain);
    ...
}
```

Any difference between those two when igniting the root saga?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually two differences here.

**1. Using effects vs calling the sagas directly.**

The redux-saga library can handle yielding generators directly, however this approach makes it hard to use mocks when writing tests. Instead, you can use the `call` effect. This code will work exactly the same as your first snippet except it is written declaratively using the `call` effect. (Also, I am using the `all` effect here, as yielding an array has been deprecated).

```
function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        call(cycleRoot), 
        call(cycleChain),
        ...
    ]);
}
```

For a slightly more in-depth insights (including example of a test) I suggest reading this part of redux-saga documentation: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects.html

*You can use the `call` effect to call both functions and sagas. However, if you are not interested in writing tests and are sure you never will, I found it useful to use the `call` effect to differentiate between calling sagas (use `call`) and regular functions (call directly).*

**2. Using `fork` instead of `call`**

The second difference is that in your first snippet you are blocking rootSaga execution until all the sagas are finished. To make them non-blocking you can use the `fork` effect.

```
function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        call(cycleRoot), 
        call(cycleChain),
        ...
    ]);
    console.log('This happens only after all sagas are finished (including fetching etc.')
}

function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        fork(cycleRoot), 
        fork(cycleChain),
        ...
    ]);
    console.log('This happens immediately after the sagas are executed - it does not wait for async action like fetching')
}
```

Again you can read up on non-blocking calls in the documentation: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/NonBlockingCalls.html

**In conclusion** I suggest always using effects (like `call`/`fork`) when calling other sagas and to use the `fork` effect to startup other sagas in root saga unless there is a good reason to block it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So if my rootSaga just has a bunch of watchers with only `takeEvery` in each function, the 2nd difference should not matter right, because the watchers are all executed immediately and there is no blocking?

Comment: @wisdomtoothman yup, takeEvery uses fork internally so it is non-blocking